# How to remove raster pixels based on proportional coverage of other raster, R

Tags: r, raster, masking, cover

I have two rasters of different resolution and what I want is to mask out areas of raster A based on proportional cover of raster B. For example, I want to mask out pixels of raster A, if at least the 1/3 of them is covered by raster B.
I have no idea how to do this, so any help will be appreciated.

```
library(raster)

A <- raster(matrix(1:60,3,4))
B <- raster(matrix(1:20,5,6))
```

Comment: hi, could you add the packages you use?

Comment: hi @JohannesStötzer, the main package that I use for this is  the raster package. Since I have never done such calculation, I am not aware of any other package that could possibly help me solve this.

Comment: Since you didn't specify a coordinate system for both raster object, both have an extent of 0-1. Therefore, A is completely covered by B. What exactly do you want? And what exactly do you mean by 'covered by raster B'

Comment: @geo_dd Can you elaborate A) how you would define "proportional cover of raster" and B) give an expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Your rasters are different resolutions over the same extent between 0 and 1 on x and y. A is 4x3, B is 6x5.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2)) 
plot(A)
plot(B)
```

[image]

One first step could be to align the two to have the same resolution, so that we can apply the mask function. The raster::disaggregate function splits each cell into an integer number of columns an rows. In this case, with low resolution, I can split each cell into the number of columns and rows of the other matrix, so the four columns of A can each be split into 6, and the six columns of B can be split into 4, such that both are 24 wide. (Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35634217/6851825) for help.)

```
A_resize <- disaggregate(A, fact = c(dim(B)[2], dim(B)[1]), method = "bilinear") 
B_resize <- disaggregate(B, fact = c(dim(A)[2], dim(A)[1]), method = "bilinear")
par(mfrow=c(1,2)) 
plot(A_resize)
plot(B_resize)
```

[image]

I'm interpreting your question to mean you want to mask out A when the values of B in that same place are < 1/3 of max.

We could make a modified version of `B_resize` which reclassifies everything < 1/3 of max as an NA. (Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50843274/6851825) for help.)

```
B_mask <- reclassify(B_resize, 
                     rbind(c(0, B@data@max * 1/3, NA), 
                           c(B@data@max * 1/3,  B@data@max, 1)))
plot(B_mask)
```

[image]

and we could then use that to mask A:

```
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
plot(mask(A_resize,B_mask))
```

[image]